# how to inject javascript function and call it later using gecofx

Tags: javascript, c#, geckofx

I am using GeckoFX 29 as well as xulrunner.

```
            string text = " function hi(){ return 1;}";
            GeckoElement script = geckoWebBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
            script.SetAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script.SetAttribute("language", "javascript");
            GeckoTextNode popText = geckoWebBrowser.Document.CreateTextNode(text);
            script.AppendChild(popText);
            geckoWebBrowser.Document.Head.AppendChild(script);
```

later on i am calling this function like this.

```
using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser.Window.JSContext))
            {
    context.EvaluateScript(" hi();" , out result);
}
```

i am not getting the value return by function hi result is empty evaluate script is returning false.

what is wrong with this any help ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that appending a script to the document like that causes it to be parsed.

But executing the script like this should have the desired effect of adding the function:

```
string text = " function hi(){ return 1;}";
using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser.Window.JSContext))
{
    context.EvaluateScript(text, out result);
}
```

And then later on you can call it like you were:

```
using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser.Window.JSContext))
{
        context.EvaluateScript(" hi();" , out result);
}
```

Comment: I already realized and fixed it.. anyhow thanks for your interest.